# With the $uwv$ method, why can $3v^2$ be negative?

Tags: uvw

If we define $3v^2 = ab+bc+ca$, then doesn't that mean $3v^2$  must be positive due to the exponentiation and positive $3$?

I note that if for example $a = −1, b = −2, c = 3$ we get $3v^2 = −7$! I understand that the algebra is not tricking me but I am just not convinced that two positives multiply to form a negative.

Comment: Without any explanation (uwv method?) the problem is meaningless.

Comment: The definition you started with does not guarantee results within the real numbers...

Comment: Here's a much simpler example of the same difficulty. If we define $v^2=a$, then for example if $a=-1$, we get $v^2=-1$. Which has no (real) solution. There are three ways out. One, allow nonreal solutions. Two, forbid negative values of $a$. Three, accept that you have no business defining $v^2=a$. To decide which path to follow, you must know why you decided to define $v^2=a$. We don't know why you decided to define $3v^2=ab+bc+ca$, so we can't help you.

Comment: The [uvw method](https://brilliant.org/wiki/the-uvw-method/) is applied for **non-negative reals**. We use AM-GM (and other inequalities) to establish the results (which is why we need the terms to be non-negative). Sp, $ 3v^2 =ab+bc+ca$ cannot be negative by definition.